# php blowfish encryption in Windows

Tags: php, windows, encryption, blowfish

I'm trying to use blowfish encryption in my php project but it won't decrypt on Windows.

encrypt

```
    $bf = Crypt_Blowfish::factory('cbc');
    $bf->setKey('domain.com', 'qwe456+=');
    return $bf->encrypt($text);
```

decrypt

```
    $bf = Crypt_Blowfish::factory('cbc');
    $bf->setKey('domain.com', 'qwe456+=');
    return $bf->decrypt($text);
```

In the result I get some strange symbols. On CentOS server it works fine. What can be the reason?

Comment: What exactly is the `Crypt_Blowfish` class? It's not standard PHP...

Comment: It's from here http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish/download